# How to avoid reading Decimal value as Float in Openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, openrowset

In my excel, some values are like this

```
11.17
3.35
2.28
1.4
```

stored in `General` type.

After importing the excel to database some values decimal places are completely getting changed.

Example

```
SELECT * into #temp 
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',    
                    'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;Database=D:\test\testfile.xlsx',
                     [Data$])
```

the data from `#temp` will be inserted in destination table with datatype `decimal(38,20)`.

```
11.17 is changed to 11.17000000000000000000
3.35 is changed to 3.35000000000000010000
2.28 is changed to 2.27999999999999980000--wrong
1.4 is changed to 1.39999999999999990000--wrong
```

upon checking I found the datatype of column in `#temp` is `float`, which is causing this issue as its a approximate datatype.

Is there a way to avoid storing it in float ?

I know we can us `BULK` option with `fmt` file, but the number of columns in excel is not static so I cannot use that option.

Comment: What's your *table's* schema? Where do you store this value? If the target field is ` float` the result will suffer from rounding errors. Besides, those may be the *actual* values. Excel itself doesn't have decimals. It has some very simple types based on VB6 types. How you see cell text depends on the cell's formatting. You may have to round values to the desired accuracy. After all, decimals are floating point types themselves and some numbers simply don't have an exact representation even when a large decimal is used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Am storing the values in `decimal(38,20)`. I have mentioned the same in question.

Comment: Not really - `the data from #temp will be inserted in destination table with datatype decimal(38,20).` doesn't say anything about the #temp table's schema. In any case you'll have to check what the *Excel raw data* is, not what the text display shows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - If you watch the query closely, the `openrowset` result is directly inserted into `#temp` table

Comment: Which doesn't explain anything, nor does it show the *table's* definition. The fields in the table could still be floats. And the Excel data may still be imprecise.

Comment: First of all, check what the *actual* values are in Excel. Set the cell format to Text for example to see what's actually stored in the cell. In the worst case, `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. You could extract those files and check what the fields contain

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Consider my excel has two columns, one is `FName` and next one is `Fvalue`. I have issue with storing `Fvalue` in my database

Comment: Another option is to use SSIS, which will allow you to configure how fields are read, including types and precisions.

Comment: `Consider my excel has two columns` that says *nothing* about the contents. Don't force people to guess.

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way:

```
SELECT * as [Decimal] into #temp 
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',    
                    'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;Database=D:\test\testfile.xlsx',
                     [Data$])
```

It may fuss about * as [Decimal]. You should select [ColumnName] as [Decimal].

Comment: That's not valid SQL. Even if it were, renaming a field won't change its type